# How can I print a variables stored in a dictionary to screen using a for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two dictionaries as follows:

```
superhero_dict  = {
    u'phone_number_4': u'07400000000', 
    u'phone_number_3': u'02000000000', 
    u'phone_number_2': u'02010000000', 
    u'phone_number_1': u'07500000000', 
    u'full_name': u'Bruce Wayne'
}

superhero_dict =    {
    u'phone_number_3': u'02000000001', 
    u'phone_number_2': u'02010000001', 
    u'phone_number_1': u'07500000001', 
    u'full_name': u'Peter Parker',
    u'secret_name': u'Spiderman'
}
```

I would like to have a for loop that prints the phone numbers of each superhero to screen. The complication is that each dictionary has a different number of (a) keys and (b) phone numbers. The format of the phone number key is consistent i.e. "phone_number_" + integer as shown in the examples.

The best I could come up with was

```
for secret_number in range(1,10):
    try:
        print superhero_dict["phone_number_"+str(secret_number)]
    except:
        break
```

There are two issues with this approach:

1. I don't want to use some arbitrary upper limit (10 in the above example)
2. It doesn't seem very elegant/pythonic

Comment: If you made this dict, consider making `dict['phone_number']` a list of phone numbers. That will be much more friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak it so there's no limit:

```
import itertools

for num in itertools.count(1): # count up from 1 infinitely
    phone = superhero_dict.get('phone_number_' + str(num))
    if phone is None:
        break
    print phone
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple comprehension;

```
print '\n'.join(superhero_dict[x] for x in superhero_dict 
                                  if x.startswith("phone_number"))
```

EDIT: In case you didn't see it, check nneonneo's comment above, the better structure will make it even easier/more obvious.

Comment: Note that this solution may give the phone numbers out of order, which may or may not be OK.

Comment: @nneonneo Good point, of course you could do a numeric ordering by key, but that'd get really messy :-/ We'll see what the OP needs.